# Cambiar un JButton a visible o no según el valor de un campo de MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un trabajo de grado de una interfaz gráfica en Java con Netbeans, en el cual necesito leer un valor de una base de datos MySQL y, de acuerdo a ese valor poner visible o no un Jbutton.

Aquí les mando mi código (vean los 2 comentarios en mayúsculas de donde estoy teniendo problemas):

Ejemplo:

Si el valor en la base de datos de `cap1` es igual a 0, no muestres el `JButton`, y si es igual a 1 sí muestres el `JButton`.

```
public class capitulos extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Conectar cc = new Conectar();
Connection cn = cc.conexion();

  String cap1;
 String cap2;
 String cap3;
 String cap4;
 String cap5;   
 String cap6;
 int cap11;
 String usuario;


public capitulos(String dato) {        
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//colocar la ventana en el medio
    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon ("D:\\Christian\\Proyectos NetBeans\\Prueba2\\src\\Imagenes\\IconDesktop.png");
    this.setIconImage(icono.getImage());//esta y la linea anterior sirven para poner el logo de la aplicacion en el escritorio

   inicio a = new inicio();
    usuario = dato;

    System.out.println("esta es la variable " +  
                       "\n " + usuario );


    String sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario='"+usuario+"'";

    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            cap1=rs.getString("Capitulo1");
            System.out.println("cap1 ="+ cap1);
            cap2=rs.getString("Capitulo2");
            System.out.println("cap2 ="+ cap2);
            cap3=rs.getString("Capitulo3");
            System.out.println("cap3 ="+ cap3);
            cap4=rs.getString("Capitulo4");
            System.out.println("cap4 ="+ cap4);
            cap5=rs.getString("Capitulo5");
            System.out.println("cap5 ="+ cap5);
            cap6=rs.getString("Capitulo6");
            System.out.println("cap6 ="+ cap6);//falta revisar esto a la hora de cambiar los capitulos (cap1,cap2,cap3...)


        }

         if (cap1.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("cap 1 = 1 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap1.setVisible(true); ESTO ES LO QUE NO PUEDO EJECUTAR ME DA ERROR
             // TituloCap1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);ESTO ES LO QUE NO PUEDO EJECUTAR ME DA ERROR

        } else {
            System.out.println("cap 1 = 0 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap1.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            //TituloCap1.setVisible(false);
        }

        if (cap2.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("cap 2 = 1 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap2.setVisible(true);
            //TituloCap2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            System.out.println("cap 2 = 0 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap2.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            //TituloCap2.setVisible(false);
        }    

        if (cap3.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("cap 3 = 1 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap3.setVisible(true);
            //TituloCap3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            System.out.println("cap 3 = 0 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap3.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            //TituloCap3.setVisible(false);
        }

        if (cap4.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("cap 4 = 1 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap4.setVisible(true);
            //TituloCap4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            System.out.println("cap 4 = 0 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap4.setVisible(false);
            //TituloCap4.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        }

        if (cap5.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("cap 5 = 1 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap5.setVisible(true);
            //TituloCap5.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            System.out.println("cap 5 = 0 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap5.setVisible(false);
            //TituloCap5.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        }

        if (cap6.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("cap 6 = 1 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap6.setVisible(true);
            //TituloCap6.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            System.out.println("cap 6 = 0 " +  
                       "\n ");
            //TituloCap6.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            //TituloCap6.setVisible(false);
        }  




    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    }








public capitulos() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//colocar la ventana en el medio
    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon ("D:\\Christian\\Proyectos NetBeans\\Prueba2\\src\\Imagenes\\IconDesktop.png");
    this.setIconImage(icono.getImage());//esta y la linea anterior sirven para poner el logo de la aplicacion en el escritorio

    cap1="";
   cap2="";
    cap3="";
    cap4="";
    cap5="";   
    cap6="";
    cap11=1;
    usuario="";





}        
private void BhomeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    modos abrir = new modos();
    abrir.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}                                     

private void BlogoutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    inicio abrir = new inicio();
    abrir.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}                                       

private void Bcap1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    IniCapitulo abrir = new IniCapitulo();       
    abrir.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);

    System.out.println(cap1);
}                                     

private void TituloCap2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

}                                           

private void TituloCap1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(capitulos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(capitulos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(capitulos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(capitulos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new capitulos().setVisible(true);


        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton Batras;
private javax.swing.JButton Bavanzar;
private javax.swing.JButton Bcap1;
private javax.swing.JButton Bcap2;
private javax.swing.JButton Bcap3;
private javax.swing.JButton Bcap4;
private javax.swing.JButton Bcap5;
private javax.swing.JButton Bcap6;
private javax.swing.JButton Bguardar;
private javax.swing.JButton Bhome;
private javax.swing.JButton Blogout;
private javax.swing.JButton BotonSalir;
private javax.swing.JButton Bquestion;
private javax.swing.JLabel Fondo;
private javax.swing.JPanel JPanelSecundario;
private javax.swing.JLabel Titulo;
private javax.swing.JLabel Titulo1;
private javax.swing.JButton TituloCap1;
private javax.swing.JButton TituloCap2;
private javax.swing.JButton TituloCap3;
private javax.swing.JButton TituloCap4;
private javax.swing.JButton TituloCap5;
private javax.swing.JButton TituloCap6;
private javax.swing.JPanel barra;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   





}
```

Comment: En los comentarios mencionas "*me da error*"... Bueno, cuál es el error textual que te da? ¿podrías [edit] la pregunta para agregarlo(s)?

Comment: Además del error que te pide @Mariano podrías agregar también dónde instancias el botón `TituloCap1`

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Se necesita saber cual error te aparece para que te podamos ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente sea `NullPointerException`, yo no veo en ningún lado que se cree una instancia de TituloCap1, seguramente se solucione con:

```
TituloCap1 = new JButton("boton TituloCap1");
```

Seguramente pasará con el resto de los componentes que no hayan sido [instanciados](http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=411:conceptos-de-objetos-y-clases-en-java-definicion-de-instancia-ejemplos-basicos-y-practicos-cu00619b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188)

Le recomiendo también utilizar [convenciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_nombres_(programaci%C3%B3n)#Java) apropiadas de Java.